# What are the equivalent directives for forcing a function inline for various compilers?

Tags: c++, solaris, aix

In order to force a function to be inlined, various C++ compiler vendors have provided various non-standard extensions

```
╔═══════════╦════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Compiler  ║           Directive            ║                  Documentation Link                   ║
╠═══════════╬════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ VC++      ║ __forceinline                  ║ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx ║
╠═══════════╬════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ gcc/CLANG ║ __attribute__((always_inline)) ║ https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2007-01/msg00049.html ║
╠═══════════╬════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Solaris   ║ inline __hidden                ║                                                       ║
╚═══════════╩════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Do we have anything similar for [IBM XL C/C++ for AIX](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/xlcpp-aix/), [aC++ for HP-UX](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801/?ciid=6b080f1bace021100f1bace02110275d6e10RCRD) and [IBM zOS XL C/C++](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/czos/). Also for Solaris, the mentioned directive I discovered out by hacking through few open source headers. Can any one provide me a link to the documentation

Comment: @closevoter: Why is this off-topic? And can you please elaborate why you think this asks for recommendation of book/tool or software library?

Comment: `__hidden` apparently [doesn't have anything to do with inlining](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37075/bkaee.html).

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37075/bkamw.html#indexterm-id-764) looks like Solaris' way of doing it.

Comment: @Abhijit *Can any one provide me a link to the documentation* Close reason: *other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow* That is probably why.